# How to create a link to switch language in ASP.NET Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

A website supports several languages. The code to support multi-language including the routes are already in place and working.

The localization is set up using the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` as explaned at https://joonasw.net/view/aspnet-core-localization-deep-dive.

```
app.UseRouter(routes =>
{
    routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=en-US}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
    {
        subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

        subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
        {
             // Routes are here
        }   
    });
});
```

How to create a generic  tag which will show the current page in a different language?

Ideally, I would just specify which language this link should point to and that it should keep all other route parameters (like the current controller, the current action, the current route model) so I can have this link in the `_Layout.cshtml`?

Comment: I don't think I fully understand this yet. Are you thinking of giving the user the ability to switch one page (temporarily) to a different language without changing the UIculture? If so, are you thinking of one specific language or shall that be dynamic in any fashion?

Comment: No, the link should point to the current page/view just in a different language (in most cases, if the current page is /en-US/about, the link should point to /de-DE/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this with the partial view for language dropdown list.

- First get a list of supported cultures by injecting `RequestLocalizationOptions` to the partial view
- Collect route data values and query string parameters as well into a dictionary, so if you have a link like below it will catch all parameters.

  > /en-US/Products/?page=5&keyword=bla-bla-bla
- Loop in the supported cultures to create links and replace `{culture}` route value with the appropriate in the loop. The only thing to consider is to have `{culture}` defined in the global route.

here is my `_Languages.cshtml` partial view:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options

@inject IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions> LocOps

@{
    var requestCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;

    var supportedCultures = LocOps.Value.SupportedUICultures

        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = $"{c.Name}",
            Text = $"{c.DisplayName}"
        }).ToList();

    var routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var r in ViewContext.RouteData.Values)
    {
        routeData.Add(r.Key, r.Value.ToString());
    }

    foreach(var qs in Context.Request.Query)
    {
        routeData.Add(qs.Key, qs.Value);
    }
}

<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="btn-sm btn-default border border-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownLang" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @($"{requestCulture.DisplayName}")
    </a>

    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownLang">
        @foreach (var culture in supportedCultures)
        {
            if (culture.Value.ToLower() != requestCulture.Name.ToLower())
            {
                // replace {culture} value with the one from the list
                routeData["culture"] = culture.Value;

                <a class="dropdown-item small"
                   asp-all-route-data="@routeData">
                    @culture.Text
                </a>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

btw, I'm using bootstrap 4.

### UPDATE

I created a nuget package that creates a language navigation menu with one line of code :)

- install nuget package

```
PM > Install-Package LazZiya.RazorLibrary -Version 1.0.1
```

- create a language navigaton dropdown:

```
<partial name="/Areas/LazZiya/Pages/_LanguageMenu.cshtml" />
```

compatible with .NetCote 2.1 or later and bootstrap 4

- notice : Route key name must be `culture`

#### UPDATE 2 (14.04.2019)

I created a tag helper that supports all versions of current dotnet core frameworks to create a language navigation depending on supported cultures or manually selected list of cultures.

install nuget package (it contains another useful tag helpers as well):

```
Install-Package LazZiya.TagHelpers -Version 2.0.0
```

add tag helpers to _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@addTagHelper *, LazZiya.TagHelpers
```

Create the language naviation :

```
<language-nav view-context="ViewContext"></language-nav>
```

for more details visit [project website](http://ziyad.info/en/articles/27-LazZiya_TagHelpers), see [live demos](http://demo.ziyad.info/en/LanguageNav)

Answer (score 0):

This is not super elegant but it should do the trick. Here as an example for en-US and de-DE only:

```
var switchLang = new Dictionary<string, string>{{"de-DE", "en-US"}, {"en-US", "de-DE"}};
var controller = Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
var action = Html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
var lang = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name;
var newLang = lang;
switchLang.TryGetValue(lang, out newLang);
```

You can then use the variable controller, action and newLang to build an ActionLink to the other language. I just put a line into one of my _Layout.cshtml like to show the value of

```
var url = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",newLang, controller, action);
```

And it looked OK.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds really like an emergency hack :) I hope there is a more elegant/generic way to achieve that.

Comment: It might help if you defined more clearly what language link to use when and what default to use. Also how exactly language routing happens.